# object reference not set to an instance of an object - storyboard.begin()

Tags: c#-4.0

I have this *code- behind.* i want to start another `x:Key = "CardAnimation1"` storyboard on completion of previous storyboard.

```
private void Storyboard_Completed_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();            
    sb= (Storyboard)this.Resources["CardAnimation1"];
    sb.Begin();

}
```

i am getting that exception in sb.begin().. donno why ? any help can be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.Resources["CardAnimation1"]` is empty/doesn't exist.

You are assigning a `null` value to `sb`, replacing the value you had initialized it with.

You then call `.Begin` on this `null` value, causing the exception.

Solution:

Make sure `this.Resources["CardAnimation1"]` has the correct value in it.